# Custom Progressbar in android

Tags: android-custom-view, android-drawable, native-android

In search of better solution for custom two side Progressbar as shown in images.
the image shows progress bar with two colours indicating two different progresses.

[image: Expected result using custom view]

here the percentage and colour both are the variable values.
with existing implementation the percentage is variable but not the progress colours.

drawable in use.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#4CAF50" />
        <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FD5829" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: If you are looking for UX solutions, then please head over to https://ux.stackexchange.com/ and research your question over there. SO is for specific programming related questions